# How to return numbers in a string file (txt)?

Tags: string, parsing, numbers, return

I want to parse a txt file with information.
That i want is, to find all numbers in that string
I mean that i want a sub to return the first number (as many digits as is the number ) after the second one , the third one etc.
Is it possible?

Comment: try using a programming language. Perl or Python seem fit for the job, one regexp can get you to your goal

Answer (score 1):

$string = preg_replace('/\D/', ' ', $string);

$numberArray = explode(' ',$string);